# Function that steps numbers based on input?

Tags: python

Is there a function in python that lets me input a number (i.e `3`) and a beginning and end number and steps accordingly:

function `(10, 21, 2)` **->** `[15, 20]`

function `(0, 16, 5)` **->** `[3, 6, 9, 12, 15]`

Comment: Why does `0,16,3` give `[3,6,9,12,15]`, whereas `10, 21, 2` gives `[15, 20]`?

Comment: You mean like listing numbers in a range? That would be the `range` function.

Comment: Your example is contradictory. In the first example the 3rd parameter is "number of steps" and in your second example the 3rd parameter is "size of each step"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish your task using the `range` fucntion. The base syntax is:

```
range(start, end, step)
range(1, 10, 2) = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
range(1, 10, 5) = [1, 6]
```

More info: http://www.pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/

Comment: Note that `range()` only returns a `list` in Python 2. It returns a `range` object in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

Range is the function which does the same :

```
for a in range(0,16,3):
    print a
```

Better follow some tutorials these are very basics of python .

Comment: Your indentation is off.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use in a for loop you want - `range(<start>,<end>,<Step>)`